# Reloading Img to memorystream causes a [ A generic error occurred in GDI+ ]

Tags: c#, winforms, memorystream

am having a problem when i attempt to  update  a Record image in the DB.

the workflow am using goes as follows :

1. the user loads the image to a picture box using FilaDialog.

   ```
        DialogResult path = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (path == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            pictureBox.Refresh();
        }
   ```
2. after the user finishes inserting the remaining fields and attempts to save the Image is loaded from the PictureBox and saved to the db.

   ```
    Image img = PictureBox.Image;
    byte[] photo_aray = null;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
             {
                    img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    photo_aray = new byte[ms.Length];
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    ms.Read(photo_aray, 0, photo_aray.Length);
             }
   ```

so far so good, but the problem occurs when i attempt to update the Image which follows as such :

1. the user selects the Record from a list, an event loads Record information, image is loaded to a PictureBox.
2. after the user finishes updating the remaining fields and attempts to save the Image is loaded from the PictureBox and saved to the db using the same logic written above with some changes to the SQL query.

   ```
    Image img = PictureBox.Image;
    byte[] photo_aray = null;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
             {
                    img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg); // BREAKING POINT
                    photo_aray = new byte[ms.Length];
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    ms.Read(photo_aray, 0, photo_aray.Length);
             }
   ```

Every time the user attempts to update, the following error message is shown :

> A generic error occurred in GDI+.::   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
> at System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageFormat format)

**note that if the user changes the image or simply choose the same image using the Filedialog no error occurs.**

any help is appreciated.

****** EDIT #1 *********

just to clarify,

1. records are first loaded from the database into RecordsList object which is bound to a List.
2. when a user selects a certain record, the Image is loaded from the Selected Record to the PictureBox.
3. if no changes are made to the picture , the image is loaded from picturebox to the logic explained above.

Comment: *the user selects the Record from a list, an event loads Record information, image is loaded to a PictureBox.*: What happens here? BTW, you don't need that `photo_aray`, you can just return `ms.ToArray()`. Try not to dispose of the MemoryStream when you assign the Image back to the PictureBox.

Comment: @Jimi the record information are stored in the db, and are displayed in a listbox with a custom bound datasource. so whenever the user selects a record i can access the object containing all information. as for the photo_array, am further using it to store the image to db. please note that records are first loaded from the database into RecordsList object, when a user selects a certain record, the Image is loaded from the RecordsList object to the PictureBox. thanks for your help.

Comment: That's what I asked about, the part that loads the byte array from your DB up to the PictureBox. If you need that `photo_aray` (you actually don't need it, you could move that code to a method that returns an array), you can just write `photo_aray = ms.ToArray()` and remove the `Read()` call, which is useless and also prone to errors.

Comment: I assume that you do the same thing when you load the byte array from your DB: use a MemoryStream and dispose of it with a `using` statement. Try NOT to do that. Also, you're forcing the JPEG format when you save the Image: you should use the `Image.RawFormat` (which gives you the original format of the Image).

Comment: @Jimi wouldn't not disposing of the MemoryStream overload the memory?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Note that I'm referring to the procedure that assigns a Bitmap to a PictureBox built using the byte array coming from your DB. More in general, the MemoryStream object doesn't actually use any unmanaged resources. Of course, since it's disposable, you dispose of it when what uses it doesn't need it anymore. When you use it to get the byte array of an Image, after that, it's useless. When you use this Stream to generate an Image from, you can leave the Stream *active* while the Image is *alive*. Anyway, you dispose of a `PictureBox.Image` before you assign another, right?, so...

Comment: It's when you assign a Bitmap to a PictureBox and you don't dispose of the previous one, if any (e.g., `pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose(); pictureBox1.Image = [Some Image]`) that you're leaking GDI resources. The Garbage Collector won't help you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mr. @Jimi , I've managed to solve the issue.

as he so kindly pointed out, i need to dispose of the Memory stream after saving the object.

so my code was edited like this :

```
Image img = PictureBox.Image;
byte[] photo_aray = null;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg); 
photo_aray = new byte[ms.Length];
ms.Position = 0;
ms.Read(photo_aray, 0, photo_aray.Length);
//
//
//SQL UPDATE HERE
//
//
ms.Close();
ms.Dispose();
```

Thanks!